# Google Index: Using final URL or Link

Tags: php, url, drupal, drupal-7, google-search

This may seem like a basic question (and I've searched for the answer), but I'm wondering if anyone knows whether Google indexes using the final URL displayed (in the address bar), or just the link it used to get there (or both).

A client has a Drupal 7 website with product category links in friendly URL format, e.g.

```
website.com/product/cat/bedroom
```

...which is perfectly fine for the primary Menu, but when using the filtering menu I would like those links to be "standard" PHP Queries e.g.

```
/?q=product/cat/bedroom/cat/bathroom
```

This can be achieved quite easily as Drupal (and obviously PHP) already accept the query and just requires editing of the filter block's link.  However, when landing on that filtered page the URL will drop the query and revert to the friendly URL.  My question is, will Google index that URL, or the link's query URL - or both?

The ultimate goal is to block Google from indexing the q parameter, meaning it won't dive deep into filtering, which has resulted in tens of thousands of useless indexes, and only have the pages linked directly to with friendly URLs.

Comment: Google spiders the URLs exactly as it finds them. If one of the pages has a [canonical link](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls), that will be used instead (assuming it is valid). If your filters are drop downs or any type of form field, those won’t be followed.

Comment: The filters currently are direct dynamic links, and are being followed. Google currently has been building an index by linking to one filter option at a time, going to each page and indexing along the way, resulting in indexes like: "product/cat/bedroom/cat/bathroom/cat/toilet/cat/kitchen/brand/brandA/brand/brandB/cat/outdoor/range/chairs".  The functionality of the site works, but I'm just wondering if Google will be able to index that deep if the link it clicks on has a blocked parameter (q) even though the landed page displayed URL has that parameter removed again.

Comment: Google indexes long URLs, but keeping it under 1,000 characters is a [recommendation](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/x/318739/). One thing to consider is if `product/cat/bedroom/cat/toilet/` and `product/cat/toilet/cat/bedroom/` are identical.